# Apache returning httpd/unix-directory content-type for html files

Tags: apache, aem, content-type, dispatcher

I'm using Apache configured with AEM's dispatcher. On seemingly random occasions, the server returns a content type of 'httpd/unix-directory'. The user is then prompted to download the page in their browser. This response is then cached & subsequent requests to the home page present the user with a file download for index.html

How can I enforce text/html for all files with a .html extension?

Comment: I think it would make more sense to find out _why_ your http server shows that extremely strange behavior.

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be a race condition.

Folder paths were being created with file extensions and cached. When that file was called (which was actually a parent folder to another file) it returned type as unix-directory.

The flow was something like this:

1. Request file: /path/to/filename.jpg/version/filename_120x120.jpg
2. Folder structure above was created, with filename_120x120.jpg returned & cached at Apache
3. Request file: /path/to/filename.jpg (which exists), returned 'file' to browser which was actually a file type.

Resolution:
Do not cache files where the parent folder structure contains a "."